# Python error running script from command line due to window-build-tools

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmd, python-import, python-module

I installed window-build-tools recently and I found it doesn't work in command prompt.
I manage to find that the path of the interpreter is different.
When I run from VScode(Teamsjoin.py):

```
import sys
import pyautogui
print(sys.executable)
>C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

When I type python and run this from command Prompt.

```
C:\Users\1>python
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe'
```

But when I run script from command prompt:

```
C:\Users\1\Documents\Teamsjoin.py
>C:\Users\1\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\Documents\Teamsjoin.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ImportError: No module named pyautogui
```

I want to select python 3.9.1 interpreter in command prompt. System environment variables don't include any of the window build-tools.
 **Please help**

Comment: on Linux I have all versions in one folder which is in `PATH` and then I can decide what to use `python2 script.py` or `python3 script.py` or even `python3.7 script.py` `python3.9 script.py`

Comment: I selected python3.9 in the system environment and delete windows-build-tools\python27 path but It automatically added on the system environment variable again. And I also tried to add module files in the windows-build-tools\python27 path but adding all module is so difficult.